# How can I show data using ng2 charts and Angular correctly from an API

Tags: angular, firebase, api, graphics

Hello could you help me please? I'm trying to show data using ng2 charts in an Angular app, I'm getting the data from a API  with Firebase but It doesn't work and I don't what I'm doing wrong.

The data that I get looks like this:

```
{
    "2017": {
        "bebes": 67,
        "hombres": 20,
        "mujeres": 30
    },
    "2018": {
        "bebes": 33,
        "hombres": 10,
        "mujeres": 49
    },
    "2019": {
        "bebes": 45,
        "hombres": 20,
        "mujeres": 34
   }
```

(it's awfull, I know).

I've created a service to fetch the data just with a metho.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class VentasService {

  private url = 'https://dbb-fa0a5.firebaseio.com/data.json';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  getVentas() {
    return this.http.get(this.url);
  }
}
}
```

And this is the component with the graphic bar.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ChartOptions, ChartType, ChartDataSets } from 'chart.js';
import { Label } from 'ng2-charts';   
import { VentasService  } from '../../../../services/ventas.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-bar-grafic',
  templateUrl: './bar-grafic.component.html',
  styles: []
})
export class BarGraficComponent {
  year_2017: any = []
  year_2018: any = []
  year_2019: any = []

  constructor(private ventas : VentasService){

  this.ventas.getVentas().subscribe( (data : any) =>{
    this.year_2017 = data['2017']
    this.year_2018 = data['2018']
    this.year_2019 = data['2019']
    // testing
    console.log(this.year_2017.mujeres);
  })



  }

  public barChartOptions: ChartOptions = {
    responsive: true,
    // We use these empty structures as placeholders for dynamic theming.
    scales: { xAxes: [{}], yAxes: [{}] },
    plugins: {
      datalabels: {
        anchor: 'end',
        align: 'end',
      }
    }
  };

  public barChartLabels: Label[] = ['2017', '2018', '2019'];
  public barChartType: ChartType = 'bar';
  public barChartLegend = true;


  public barChartData: ChartDataSets[] = [
    { data: [this.year_2019.mujeres, this.year_2018.mujeres, this.year_2017.mujeres], label: 'Mujeres' },
    { data: [this.year_2019.hombres, this.year_2018.hombres, this.year_2017.hombres], label: 'Hombres' },
    { data: [this.year_2019.bebes, this.year_2018.bebes, this.year_2017.bebes], label: 'Bebes' }
  ];

  public refresh(): void {
    this.ventas.getVentas().subscribe( (data : any) =>{
      this.year_2017 = data['2017']
      this.year_2018 = data['2018']
      this.year_2019 = data['2019']
      console.log(this.year_2017.mujeres);

    })
  }
}
```

If I try to print it in the console, everything looks fine but the graphic doesn't show the data

[image]

And Really I don't kno why :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have checked your code and found out that the issue is you are assigning data to `barChartData` before the data has arrived from the service. As your service is performing an asynchronous operation so you need to move the code of assigning data inside the subscribe block.

Like your service is an asynchronous task, i am using `timer` operator to add asynchronous behavior.

Please find the code below:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { ChartOptions, ChartType, ChartDataSets } from "chart.js";
import { Label } from "ng2-charts";
import { timer } from "rxjs";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  year_2017: any = [];
  year_2018: any = [];
  year_2019: any = [];

  public barChartData: ChartDataSets[] = [];

  constructor() {
    timer(1000).subscribe((data: any) => {
      this.year_2017 = { mujeres: 10, hombres: 20, bebes: 30 };
      this.year_2018 = { mujeres: 5, hombres: 10, bebes: 15 };
      this.year_2019 = { mujeres: 2, hombres: 4, bebes: 6 };
      // testing
      console.log(this.year_2017.mujeres);

      this.barChartData = [
        {
          data: [
            this.year_2019.mujeres,
            this.year_2018.mujeres,
            this.year_2017.mujeres
          ],
          label: "Mujeres"
        },
        {
          data: [
            this.year_2019.hombres,
            this.year_2018.hombres,
            this.year_2017.hombres
          ],
          label: "Hombres"
        },
        {
          data: [
            this.year_2019.bebes,
            this.year_2018.bebes,
            this.year_2017.bebes
          ],
          label: "Bebes"
        }
      ];
    });
  }

  public barChartOptions: ChartOptions = {
    responsive: true,
    // We use these empty structures as placeholders for dynamic theming.
    scales: { xAxes: [{}], yAxes: [{}] },
    plugins: {
      datalabels: {
        anchor: "end",
        align: "end"
      }
    }
  };

  public barChartLabels: Label[] = ["2017", "2018", "2019"];
  public barChartType: ChartType = "bar";
  public barChartLegend = true;
}
```